# VBScript process launch results in empty labels

Tags: vbscript, process, windows-xp

I am attempting to create a program for a business owner who is not good with computers. Trying to keep it simple, I just created a simple script to launch the program and send the password and tab/enter keys to login for him.

After a lot of trial and error I managed to get it to launch, but it does not come with any text where it should be, and the OK button does not launch the application.

Here is the code I use to launch the process:

```
Function AddQuotes(input)
    AddQuotes = Chr(34) & input & Chr(34)
End Function

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

progDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES%")
pPath = progDir & "\PELCO\PELCO DX4500_DX4600 Client\Network Client\DX4500_DX4600Client.exe"

msgbox AddQuotes(pPath), 1, "test"

oShell.Run AddQuotes(pPath), 1, false
```

The program will launch, but looks like this:

[image: No Labels]

This is what the window should look like (as when launched directly from a shortcut):

[image: Labels Work]

Comment: What happens if you type the path to the program into the Start > Run box and open it from there?

Comment: Add `oShell.CurrentDirectory="your_app_working_directory"` somewhere between `Set oShell = ...` and `oShell.Run ...`. Value for `your_app_working_directory` you can copy (& paste) from the application shortcut (right click it => Properties). Maybe `oShell.CurrentDirectory = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("your_app_working_directory")` if contains an environment variable